# Table function in python

Tags: python

I am having two variables,

```
a                   b
Less than 5        Yes
Less than 5        No
Less than 5        Yes
Less than 5        No
Less than 5        Yes
Greater than 5     No
Greater than 5     Yes
Greater than 5     No
Greater than 5     Yes
```

I want to get a table which would show me,

```
                 Yes     No
Less than 5       3      2
Greater than 5    2      2
```

I basically want a table function of R in python.

Can anybody help me in doing this?

Thanks

Comment: It's best practice to provide a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that list a and b are the same length always

```
distinct = set(a)
for type in distinct:
   yes = [b[i] for i in range(len(b)) if a[i] == type].count('yes')
   no = [b[i] for i in range(len(b)) if a[i] == type].count('no')
   print type, yes, no
```

Fancy formatting not included

Answer (score 0):

```
import petl

a = ['Less than 5', 'Less than 5','Less than 5','Less than 5','Less than 5',
     'Greater than 5','Greater than 5','Greater than 5','Greater than 5',]
b = ['Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes']
cols = [a, b]
table = petl.fromcolumns(cols)

yes_table = petl.addfield(table, 'Yes_addition', lambda rec: 1 if rec['f1'] == 'Yes' else 0)
yes_table = petl.aggregate(yes_table, 'f0', sum, 'Yes_addition')
yes_table = petl.rename(yes_table, 'value', 'Yes')

no_table = petl.addfield(table, 'No_addition', lambda rec: 0 if rec['f1'] == 'Yes' else 1)
no_table = petl.aggregate(no_table, 'f0', sum, 'No_addition')
no_table = petl.rename(no_table, 'value', 'No')

joined = petl.join(yes_table, no_table, key='f0')

print petl.lookall(joined)
as_dictionary = petl.dicts(joined)
```

The above output will produce the following (as well as the as_dictionary variable will be a dictionary you can easily use elsewhere in your code):

```
+------------------+-----+----+
| f0               | Yes | No |
+==================+=====+====+
| 'Greater than 5' |   2 |  2 |
+------------------+-----+----+
| 'Less than 5'    |   3 |  2 |
+------------------+-----+----+
```

Don't forget to install petl

```
pip install petl
```